# Problem in setting JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk

I have installed JDK on path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.
To set `JAVA_HOME` variable, I opened `/etc/environment`  in gedit and added :

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"` to it.

But I got error while saving it as :

```
Could not save the file “/etc/environment”.
You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check   that you typed the location correctly and try again.
```

Where is it going wrong? How do I set JAVA_HOME variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by adding

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

to your `.bashrc` file.
You can do this by using the following steps:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal
2. type `gedit ~/.bashrc`
3. add `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"` ad the end of the file.
4. save the changes
5. type `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes to your current session.

The error message you got means that you don't have permissions to change the `/etc/environment` file. This should be possible, using `sudo`.

Comment: How can I add this to .bashrc?

Comment: @PrachiPanditrao I edited my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you. I saved that file. But on terminal I got error :                                         (gedit:7388): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:7388): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: That should be no Problem ;-) you can check if it worked by typing `echo $JAVA_HOME`. This should result in your directory. BTW, if the answer solved your Problem, you should click the grey checkmark on the left to mark it as valid.

Comment: I tried `echo $JAVA_HOME`.  But it didn't give any result. :( I will definitely click that checkmark once my problem is solved. Thank you very much though!

Comment: what is the output of  `grep -i 'JAVA' ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: output is : `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention one step. Please run `source ~/.bashrc` and then `echo $JAVA_HOME` should work

Answer (score 0):

Run <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> + `gksu gedit` and open /etc/environment. The problem is that you need elevated privileges to edit that file.